# Python - Check if value is equal to returned json response

Tags: python, json, list

Tell me if I'm wording this poorly. I'm calling a json response from the League of Legends API. I get back a response that looks like this.

```
{
"champions": [
{
    "id": 111,
    "stats": {
        "maxChampionsKilled": 2,
        "maxNumDeaths": 5,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 2,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "totalAssists": 25,
        "totalChampionKills": 2,
        "totalDamageDealt": 40838,
        "totalDamageTaken": 27900,
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 5,
        "totalDoubleKills": 0,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalGoldEarned": 11070,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 21083,
        "totalMinionKills": 56,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 12876,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalSessionsLost": 1,
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
        "totalSessionsWon": 0,
        "totalTripleKills": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 1,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0
    }
},
```

Currently I have a list like so: champ_list[] and I have all the id's (in this case 111) in this list. So completed it would be something like champ_list[111,67,4,23], and it can keep growing up to the number of champions in the game.

I then do the following:

```
if '111' in champ_list:
    print("Nautilus")
```

Here's the question - if the above statement is true and Nautilus is printed how do I get {stats},{totalSessionsPlayed} to print its value? I realized I could add

```
print(['champions'][0]['stats']['totalSessionsPlayed']
```

to the end of my statement above, however if the return data doesn't stay in the same order I'm boned. Also, if the champ_list becomes very long, it would be a pain to hardcode each line. Is there a way to do this "better" or more consistent? Sorry if I'm reaching here, but any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: if champ_list is the same order as whatever champions is in, then use `i=champ_list.index('111')` and use `['champions'][i]...`

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way for me to guarantee the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is indirectly storing an association list that maps `111` to the appropriate stat block. You should first transform this into a proper Python mapping (i.e., a `dict`):

```
json_data = { ... }
champions = {}
for d in json_data['champions']:
    champions[d['id']] = d['stats']
```

Now given `champ_id = '111'`, you can simply write

```
print(champions[champ_id]['totalSessionsPlayed'])
```

Comment: Thank you. When I follow your example I get a list of "1's" printed. Almost as if "1" is the stand for the actual data.

Comment: Never mind, I realized my mistake. I had the print() function in the if loop. Once removed it works as expected. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the result list for the id specified and pick the first element if it is found.

```
nautilus_id = 111
try:
    nautilus = filter(lambda c: c['id'] == nautilus_id, champ_list)[0]
except:
    nautilus = None
```

from there on you can access all data in nautilus:

```
print nautilus['stats']
```